# Follow-up about computing lp norm with MPI

Tags: c, array, vectors, mpi

As pointed out in the answer by Victor Eijkhout [to this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/282464/compute-lp-norm-of-a-vector-in-parallel-with-mpi?noredirect=1#comment560069_282464), the fact I am broadcasting the same vector to each process is against the MPI principles and, most importantly, will be a bottleneck for larger values of `N`. Here's how I changed my code. Now each process should own a `local_size` portion of the vector. I timed the execution using `MPI_Barrier` + `MPI_Wtime`, and the results I obtain on my machine (a MacOS with 4 cores) are:

```
Elapsed time with 1 processes: 0.014962 
Elapsed time with 2 processes: 0.004767 
Elapsed time with 3 processes: 0.003079 
Elapsed time with 4 processes: 0.002350
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Compute the p-norm of a vector, p != infinity
#define N 1000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rank, p, global_sum, norm_p;
  int local_size, local_a, local_b;
  int local_sum = 0;
  int *vec;

  double t0, t1, elapsed_time, time;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
  if (rank == 0) {
    printf("Choose the norm you want: p=0,... \n");
    scanf("%d", &norm_p);
  }
  MPI_Bcast(&norm_p, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  local_size = N / p;
  int rem = N % p;

  if (rank < rem)
    local_size++;
  
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  t0 = MPI_Wtime();
  vec = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * local_size);

  for (int i = 0; i < local_size; i++) {
    vec[i] = 1;
    printf("vec[%d] = %d \n", i, vec[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < local_size; i++) {
    local_sum += fabs(pow(vec[i], norm_p));
  }
  printf("On rank %d the computed local sum is %d \n", rank, local_sum);

  MPI_Reduce(&local_sum, &global_sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  t1 = MPI_Wtime();
  elapsed_time = t1 - t0;
  MPI_Reduce(&elapsed_time, &time, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (rank == 0) {
    printf("On rank 0 I'm showing the norm of the vector: %lf \n",
           pow(global_sum, 1. / norm_p));
    printf("Elapsed time with %d processes: %lf \n", p, time);
  }
  free(vec);

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the review goals here?

Comment: Sorry for being late. I wanted to address the comment (see link in the first line) by Victor. He was saying essentially that one shouldn't really allocate the whole vector on one process and then broadcasting it everywhere

Answer (score 3):

This code looks good. In particular I like how you handled the `rem` elements. There is a yet more elegant scheme: define `f(p) = floor( p*N/P )` and assign to process `p` the elements `f(p)` to `f(p+1)`.

See discussion: https://theartofhpc.com/istc/parallel.html#Loadbalancingversusdatadistribution

Btw, you now have some print statements in your timed section. I assume that's only for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot (again) for reviewing and for the very interesting linked discussion @VictorEijkhout

Answer (score 3):

**Allocate to the referenced object, not type**

Code obliges a reviewer to type check `vec`, which is defined someplace else.
It is easier to code right, review and maintain using the referenced object and dropping the unneeded cast.

```
//vec = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * local_size);
vec = malloc(sizeof vec[0] * local_size);
```

**Allocation skips useful check**

```
vec = malloc(sizeof vec[0] * local_size);
if (vec == NULL && local_size != 0) {
  ; // Handle out of memory error
}
```

**Overflow, imprecision risk**

Code can easily overflow the summation and lose precision.  Unclear about OP's allowed range of values to suggest a good alternation other than to use `double local_sum`.

```
local_sum += fabs(pow(vec[i], norm_p)); // Iffy code
```

Comment: @chux-Reinstate-Monica Thanks for reviewing this. I've got a question about the second point: if the 'malloc' succeeds, why do I need the if that you wrote in the second paragraph? Only because it may be that 'local_size' is 0?

Comment: @bobinthebox.  Yes, checking `malloc()` results is robust.  if `local_size == 0`, then either returning `NULL`  or non-`NULL` is OK.  Note code should still call `free()` on this pointer and `free(NULL)` is OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation